# Ioniv-v4 : ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus Not working

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, ionic-native, ionic4

This (cordova-plugin-googleplus) command is not working with IONIC-v4-BETA, please help on this issue, details mentioned below.

**Command**

> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable
>   REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=REV_KEY

**COMMAND ERROR**

```
PS C:\ROOT\yaflix\Source\DEV\yaflix> ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=com.googleusercontent.apps.****************************************
> cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus --variable REVERSED_CLIENT_ID=com.googleusercontent.apps.********************************** --save
(node:10740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
npm ERR! code ECONNRESET
npm ERR! errno ECONNRESET
npm ERR! syscall read
npm ERR! network read ECONNRESET
npm ERR! network This is a problem related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\JACK\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-08-08T05_42_29_829Z-debug.log
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (C:\Users\JACK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\cordova-common\src\superspawn.js:169:23)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:925:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:209:5)
(node:10740) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:10740) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
PS C:\ROOT\yaflix\Source\DEV\yaflix>
```

**IONIC INFO**

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)          : 4.0.3 (C:\Users\JACK\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework            : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.0
   @angular-devkit/core       : 0.7.0-rc.3
   @angular-devkit/schematics : 0.7.0-rc.3
   @angular/cli               : 6.0.8
   @ionic/ng-toolkit          : 1.0.0
   @ionic/schematics-angular  : 1.0.1
Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0

System:

   NodeJS : v8.11.3 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 5.6.0
   OS     : Windows 10

Environment:

   ANDROID_HOME : C:\Users\JACK\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools
```

**cordova plugins ls**

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.0.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
```

Comment: Hey Bro i am not sure but try this command `npm config set registry http://registry.npmjs.org/` and try `npm install` after that try your command

Comment: Hi, this solution is not working same error. any other suggestion ?

Comment: Hi, this solution is not working same error. any other suggestion ?

Comment: are you able to install other npm package ? I guess no right ?

Comment: Have changed something with network ? Like DNS or something ? is so please make it to default settings this is network issue it only happen when you have changed some settings or else this https issue can you do one thing ? run this command `npm config edit` this open the file in CMD and find the registry it will be something like this `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/` if there is https then make it http and if url for registry is something like github then change it to this `registry.npmjs.org/` let me the know result

Comment: No, Other native api is working..fine..

Comment: try this other solution

Comment: Working : Your solution 2 (Have change.....) is working fine... Thanks a lot. for support.

Comment: I will post he the answer please Accept it and give it as correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Seems Like Network Problem

Have you changed something with your network? Like DNS or something? is so please make it to default settings this is network issue it only happen when you have changed some settings or else this https issue can you do one thing?

1. Run this command `npm config edit`
2. This will open the file in CMD and find the registry it will be something like this `registry=https://registry.npmjs.org/`
3. If there is https then make it http and if the url for the registry is something like Github then change it to this `registry.npmjs.org/`.
    Let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

Google plus is decommissioned, and since you are on ionic4 you need google plus beta version to be used

check your package.json
for
    "@ionic-native/google-plus": "5.0.0-beta.0",

and import it like this
import { GooglePlus } from '@ionic-native/google-plus/ngx';

Answer (score 0):

I know it's late ... but I got the solution ... if anyone encounters this type of issue..follow the steps below ....

** Reason: ** This is happening when you have installed NPM locally and globally.

**Solution**

1. Uninstall NPM, NODE and Ionic a globally.
2. Clear all temporary files and local files related to npm and node
3. Reinstall Node and NPM

*Always do not install NPM globally.*

> Install dependencies in the local node_model folder. In global mode
>   (i.e., with the -g or - command), it establishes the current package
>   reference (i.e., the current working directory) as a global package.
>   By default, the npm install package will install all the modules
>   listed in the json as dependency.

[NPM Documentation](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install)