# Ionic: unable to create a project. "npm i" fails with 503 (Service unavailable)

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, npm-install

I have begun learning Ionic and set-up the environment accordingly. Also created sample projects, everything seemed to work fine. But now when I create a new project with

> ionic start testProject blank

I get the following error:

> npm ERR! code E503
>   npm i exited with exit code 1.

Here is my system config:

> Ionic:
>
> ionic (Ionic CLI) : 4.0.1
>
> System:
>
> NodeJS : v8.11.1
>   npm    : 5.8.0
>   OS     : Windows 10

I could not understand/rectify this error. What could be the reason for failure?

Answer (score 0):

> Something Wrong with registry URL.I answered same issue few hours back take look on the link below

[Ioniv-v4 : ionic cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-googleplus Not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51740066/ioniv-v4-ionic-cordova-plugin-add-cordova-plugin-googleplus-not-working/51741617#51741617)

I hope this help

Comment: It was down, resolved now. I am able to create an app and perform other commands as usual. Try it.